# How to bring the text of the text view when a image is placed over it

Tags: android, textview, android-imageview

I am using a `ListView` to show some options for the user.

I am using a selection image to scroll over the `ListView` to select the option.

When a selection image is placed over texts the visibility of the TextView is reduced.

can any one help me to bring the text to front of the selection image.

Comment: Going to need to see a screenshot or a much clearer explanation.

Comment: Please Explain what you want to do, post some image.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear but if I understand correctly, embed both in a Frame layout, the last view will be on top of the previous one